# Sorting in Rails: SQLite vs PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

When I order by a column (id type INT) in Rails 5 with sqlite as the development db, it sorts as expected (1,2,3,4...) but the same thing on my production environment (PostgreSQL) results in unexpected behaviour (1, 101, 102,...2, 201,...) and so on.

If I format the order as per PostgreSQL (`MyModel.order('id::integer DESC'`) then it works fine in PostgreSQL but no longer works in my development sqlite environment.

Am I overlooking something? I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: I can't speak to your problem, but I would suggest that you use the same database engine in both environments. Mixing databases is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Order works the same in Postgres, the datatype of your id column must be wrong.

Comment: Your data types are messed up. What does `.schema your_table` say in the `sqlite3` shell? How about `\d your_table` from `psql`? Keep in mind that SQLite has a very loose value-based type system rather than a column-based one (i.e. you can put a string in a column declared as an integer and SQLite won't say a thing).

Comment: My column datatype in psql was wrong. Thanks @muistooshort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your data types are messed up. What does .schema your_table say in the
>   sqlite3 shell? How about \d your_table from psql? Keep in mind that
>   SQLite has a very loose value-based type system rather than a
>   column-based one (i.e. you can put a string in a column declared as an
>   integer and SQLite won't say a thing). – mu is too short